# Get value of parameter in Javascript JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a click handler on a jQuery datatables table row - if you click a row a new dialog is launched.  However i am having soem problems getting the ID which I need to pass to my ajax function which launches the pop up.

I have the line of code below:

```
var rowData = carTable.fnGetData(event.target.parentNode);
```

If I then do the following.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(rowData);
```

If I then alert(json); I get the following pop up

```
{"ExtensionData":{}, "CarRegNo" : "ABC 123", 
"CarNumber": "98765", "CarID" : 1234, 
"CarName" : "BMW", "CarFaults" : 2, 
"CarDealerID" : 16, "DealerName" : "WeSellCars"}
```

The only value I need is the 1234 from CarID?  How can I easily get this value?

I tried the following so far with no luck - so without doing the JSON.stringify I just got the key from rowData - when I just alerted the key I could see all the different values, i.e CarID, CarRegNo - however then I tried to alret the actual value of CarID with the code below - but no response comes back - the browser just seems to hang.

```
        for (var key in rowData) {
            alert(key);
            if (key == 'CarID')
                alert(rowData[0][key]);
        }
```

Comment: You could simply use `rowData.CarId` but there is no reason for the code you show to hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should literally be just:

```
var carId = rowData.CarId;
```

The `rowData` variable already contains the single object, and `CarId` is a property of it.

Comment: Works - simple - thanks - i was over complicating things. WIll mark as accepted when I can.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need `CarID` from `rowData`:

```
var CarID = rowData.CarID
```